# Selector jquery con where

Tags: jquery

Hola tengo un problema al seleccionar estos divs con jquery y lo que quiero es seleccionar el div de `attach_preview row`. Hasta ahi bien. El problema es que quiero coger el div que justamente tenga el id del ultimo div que esta dentro.

Aqui os muestro el HTML :

```
<div class="attach_preview row">
    <div class="cl_12 row padding_bottom0_5">
        <div class="ftl" id="itemID-OT_5572400-1">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Esos divs se crean dinamicamente con lo que al crear cada uno se pone con un id diferente. Ya teniendo el codigo que me lo pasan en una variable como puedo seleccionar el primer div para vaciarlo y dejarlo en blanco.

Un saludo y muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si no te he entendido mal quieres seleccionar el elemento padre con la clase `attach_preview` de un elemento con un `id` determinado.

Puedes acceder a los "ancestros" de un elemento en el DOM a través del método `parents` de jQuery:

```js
$(function(){
  console.log($('#itemID-OT_5572400-1').parents('.attach_preview')[0]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="attach_preview row">
    <div class="cl_12 row padding_bottom0_5">
        <div class="ftl" id="itemID-OT_5572400-1">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Una vez que esta seleccionado el elemento como podria borrar su contenido html. he usado el .empty() pero no soy capaz. No se si lo estoy utilizando mal.

Comment: Lo he utlizado asi :  `$(code).parents('.attach_preview')[0].empty();`

Comment: Si en `code` tienes el identificador te faltaría `#` para indicar que el selector es por `id`. `$('#' + code).parents(....`

Comment: Sigue sin funcionarme, no consigo acceder al elemento que yo quiero.

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quieres es seleccionar el último div dentro de `cl_12` puedes usar `$('.attach_preview > .cl_12 .ftl:last-child')`, pero si bien no quisieras tomar la clase `cl_12` como referencia podrías hacer `$('.attach_preview').find('.ftl').last()`.